# Как подключить js скрипт в отдельном файле?

Tags: javascript

Извиняюсь за нубский вопрос, я просто пока что не знаю JS (изучаю java).

У меня есть форма:

```html
<form onsubmit="return checkForm(this)"action="/search" method="POST">
  <div id="fields_container">
    <div>
      <div class="element">First name:</div>
      <input id="name" type="text" name="" placeholder="James" />
      <span id="err_name" class="error"></span>
    </div>

    <div>
      <div class="element">Email:</div>
      <input id="email" type="text" name="" placeholder="example@email.com" />
      <span id="err_email" class="error"></span>
    </div>
  </div><!-- #fields_container> -->

  <div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </div>
</form>
```

и есть скрипт, который я указываю в *head*

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  function checkForm(form) {
    valid = true;

    if (document.getElementById('name').value.replace(/^\s*/, '').replace(/\s*$/, '') == "") {
      document.getElementById('err_name').innerHTML = 'Enter your first name';
      valid = false;
    } else {
      document.getElementById('err_name').innerHTML = '';
    };

    pattern = new RegExp(/^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)/i);
    emailAddress = document.getElementById('email').value;
    if (emailAddress == "") {
      document.getElementById('err_email').innerHTML = 'Enter your email';
      valid = false;
    } else if (!pattern.test(emailAddress)) {
      document.getElementById('err_email').innerHTML = 'Wrong email, please correct this field';
    } else {
      document.getElementById('err_email').innerHTML = '';
    };

    return valid;
  }; < /script>
```

т.е. при нажатии на кнопку "submit" проверяется правильность заполнения формы. Как мне этот скрипт вынести в отдельный файл и как правильно прописать его на выполнение на html-странице?

Comment: Вставить содержимое тега скрипт в ваш файл .js, без самого тега, там где раньше был тег скрипт с кодом будет <script src="путьКВашемуФайлуСоСкриптом.js"></script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Предварительно переместить код в файл main.js(только код, без тега `<script>`) и конечно же создать его. Получается когда ты прописываешь этот скрипт, то содержимое main.js подставляется.

P.S. можно писать без `type="text/javascript"`

Comment: Странно, до этого, вроде бы, делал это же самое, но не работало, теперь все отлично работает (видно, чето тупил). Спасибо!

Comment: @uncleSAM самые частые причины "чет не работало" - это 1). Неправильно прописанный путь к файлу со скриптом. 2). Одиночный самозакрывающийся тег <script src="путь" /> - не работает.

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму Возьму на заметку. Спасибо.